# Django planmember_set issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a question that I hope someone can help me with.  I'm using a form to have the user select a "plan".  Now I want to list all the members in the plan, in the form.  I have a function 'get_owners' that grabs all the members in the plan, by using this function:

```
def get_owners(self):
    owners = self.planmember_set.filter(ownership_type__code__in=["primary","joint"])
    return owners
```

Only problem is that I get an output of:

```
[<PlanMember: Doe, John (Primary)>, <PlanMember: Doe, Jane(Joint Subscriber)>, etc]
```

Now is there a way for me to just show their names and the member type (the words in brackets)?

A bit of background code.

Here is my views.py:

```
if request.POST:
    form = PlanMaturityYearForm(Plan.objects.all().filter(profile = p), request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        selected_plan = form.cleaned_data['plans']
        plan = get_object_or_404(Plan, pk=selected_plan.pk)
        investment_list = Investment.objects.all().filter(Q(plan = plan)).order_by('maturity_date')
        context['investment_list'] = investment_list
        context['plan'] = plan
        context['today'] = now
        context['current_yr'] = current_year
        context['next_yr'] = next_year
        context['show_report'] = True
else:
    form = PlanMaturityYearForm(Plan.objects.all().filter(profile = p))
context['form'] = form
return render_to_response('reports/planmaturities_year.html', RequestContext(request, context))
```

And my forms.py:

```
class PlanMaturityYearForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, plans,  *args, **kwargs):

    super(PlanMaturityYearForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['plans'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        plans,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size': 20}),
        error_messages={'required':'Please select the plan you wish to build the report for',}
    )
```

**Edit:**

models.py

```
class Plan(models.Model):
old_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
closed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
closed_date = models.DateField(null=True)
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, default=False)
plan_type = models.ForeignKey(PlanType)
ownership_type = models.ForeignKey(OwnershipType)
status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=2, default=PLAN_OPEN)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
notes = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
bank = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
account = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
transit = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
objects = PlanManager()

class Profile(models.Model):
old_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
label = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='Profile label/description')
location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True)
client = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
corp = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
noncorp = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=False)
bak_agent_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, related_name='profiles')
check1 = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
incorp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
corp_records = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
articles_of_incorp = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
other_corp_articles = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
bin = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='BIN')
phone = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
registration = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
num_sigs = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name='Number of signatures required to transaction the account')
charity = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
donations_solicited = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
ownership_type = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
ownership_other = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True) #work around for other business type selction
business_nature = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
date_incept = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
bind_power = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
reg_documents = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
other_documents = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
reg_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
tax_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
fax = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values_list`:

```
owners = self.planmember_set.filter(
             ownership_type__code__in=["primary","joint"]
         ).values_list('name', 'type')
```

Comment: where name and type are the fields Im looking to display?

Comment: thank you... Im getting close.  One last question... now Im getting an output of '7779L, 6L' instead.  Thoughts?

Comment: We probably need to see the actual models.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_owners(self):
    owners = self.planmember_set.filter(ownership_type__code__in=["primary","joint"]).values_list('name_field', 'ownership_type__code')
    return owners
```

Write where and how you use `get_owners` if not correct.

Comment: Yes that seems to help, but like I posted for Daniel,  the output I am now getting shows '7779L, 6L' instead.  Any suggestions?